# Opaque Image over transparent banner and background?

Tags: css, html, opacity

Alright for some reason my image which is 100% opaque is showing up partially transparent and showing the banner and background image behind it. How do I fix this?

Here is my style sheet:

```
#banner{
    width:1280px;
    height:80px;
    line-height:100px;
    background-color:#a8a8a8;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:40px;
    color:#00FF00;
}

#content{
    width:100%;
    font-family:comic;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:10%;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:200px;
}

#greeting{
    margin-top:-275px;
    margin-left:640px;
    font-size:25px;
}

#graphic{
    margin-left:640px;
    margin-bottom:-140px;
}

#banner{
    width:1280px;
    height:80px;
    line-height:100px;
    background-color:#a8a8a8;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:40px;
    color:#00FF00;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=25);
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#background{
    margin-bottom:-860px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=25);
}
```

here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" align="center">
</head>

<body>      
    <div id="graphic">
        <img src="jmfiller2.png" height="150">
    </div>      

    <div id="banner"></div> 

    <div id="greeting">
    Hello! Welcome to my portfolio site! 
    </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="background">
        <img src="background5.JPG">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting opacity as a property of an element in the CSS effects **everything contained** in that element.

In other words, if your banner div is set to 50%/25% opacity, everything in it will also be 50%/25% opaque.

<sub>and some HTML appears missing, unless you simply failed to post it all</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Scott is correct, you have set the *parent element* to have transparency, which will be applied to all children and there's absolutely nothing you can do to make the child opaque when the parents CSS is set to a level of transparency.

I know of two ok workarounds for this:

1. Use a tiny `PNG` image to 'simulate' the transparency with the following:

   ```
   background:url(path/to/image/semi-transparent-background.png) repeat;
   ```
2. You can [create the transparent background on a pseudo-element, using `:before` or `:after`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/).

Depending on how much backwards compatibility you want, you can choose one or both of these options, with the help of media queries and such.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your css a little bit, the banner is no longer transparent:

```
#content{
    width:100%;
    font-family:comic;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:10%;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:200px;
}

#greeting{
    margin-top:-275px;
    margin-left:640px;
    font-size:25px;
}

#graphic{
    margin-left:640px;
    margin-bottom:-140px;
}

#banner{
    width:1280px;
    height:80px;
    line-height:100px;
    background-color:#a8a8a8;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:40px;
    color:#00FF00;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#background{
    margin-bottom:-860px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=25);
}
```